# I'm having a problem with connecting the frontend and backend of a bookshop gui i am making

Tags: python, tkinter

Now so far I am working on trying to get the "search entry" function to work, but it isn't displaying the entry I attempt to search when I type in the author name, remember, I'm just trying to figure out why the entry isn't displaying in the Listbox. Here is the code. Could ya'll please identify the issue?

Frontend:

```
from tkinter import *
import backend
window = Tk()


def view_command():
    ls1.delete(0,END)
    for row in backend.view():
        ls1.insert(END, row)

def search_command():
    ls1.delete(0,END)
    for row in backend.search(title_text.get(),year_text.get(),isbn_text.get()):
        ls1.insert(END,row)
        
    
    
#Labels

l1 = Label(window, text="Title")
l1.grid(row=0, column=0)

l2 = Label(window, text="Author")
l2.grid(row=0, column=2)

l3 = Label(window, text="Year")
l3.grid(row=1, column=0)

l4 = Label(window, text="ISBN")
l4 .grid(row=1, column=2)

#Entry boxes

title_text=StringVar()
e1 = Entry(window, textvariable=title_text)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)

author_text=StringVar()
e2 = Entry(window, textvariable=author_text)
e2.grid(row=0, column=3)

year_text=StringVar()
e3 = Entry(window, textvariable=year_text)
e3.grid(row=1, column=1)

isbn_text=StringVar()
e4 = Entry(window, textvariable=isbn_text)
e4.grid(row=1, column=3)

#listbox

ls1 = Listbox(window, height=6,width=35)
ls1.grid(row=2, column=0, rowspan=6, columnspan=2)

#Scrollbar

scr1 = Scrollbar(window)
scr1.grid(row=2, column=2, rowspan=6)

#Making the scrolbar scroll down the listbox

ls1.configure(yscrollcommand=scr1.set)
scr1.configure(command=ls1.yview)

#Buttons and stuff

b1 = Button(window, text="View all", width=12, command=view_command)
b1.grid(row=2, column=3)
 
b2 = Button(window, text="Search Entry", width=12,command=search_command)
b2.grid(row=3, column=3)

b3 = Button(window, text="Add Entry", width=12)
b3.grid(row=4, column=3)

b4 = Button(window, text="Update Selected", width=12)
b4.grid(row=5, column=3)

b5 = Button(window, text="Delete Selected", width=12)
b5.grid(row=6, column=3)

b6 = Button(window, text="Exit", width=12)
b6.grid(row=7, column=3)
window.mainloop()
```

Backend:

```
import sqlite3

def connect():
    con=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cr=con.cursor()
    cr.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title text, author text, year integer, isbn integer)")
    con.commit()
    con.close()
   
def insert(title,author,year,isbn):
    con=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cr=con.cursor()
    cr.execute("INSERT INTO book VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)",(title,author,year,isbn))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
    
def view():
    con=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cr=con.cursor()
    cr.execute("SELECT * FROM book")
    rows=cr.fetchall()
    con.close()
    return rows
    
def search(title="",author="",year="",isbn=""):
    con=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cr=con.cursor()
    cr.execute("SELECT * FROM book WHERE title=? OR author=? OR year=? OR isbn=?", (title, author, year, isbn))
    rows=cr.fetchall()
    con.close()
    return rows

def delete(id):
    con=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cr=con.cursor()
    cr.execute("DELETE FROM book WHERE id=?",(id,))
    con.commit()
    con.close() 

def update(id, title, author, year, isbn):
    con=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
    cr=con.cursor()
    cr.execute("UPDATE book SET title=?, author=?, year=?, isbn=? WHERE id=?",(title,author,year,isbn,id))
    con.commit()
    con.close()

connect()
#insert("The Sun", "John Smith", 1918, 193123132)
#delete(3)
#zupdate(1, "The Moon", "John Smooth", 1917, 99999999)
#print(view())
print(search(author="John Smooth"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to add `author_text.get()` in the `search_command` function in your frontend implemenation.
Here's how the function should look:

```
def search_command():
    ls1.delete(0,END)
    for row in backend.search(title_text.get(),author_text.get(),year_text.get(),isbn_text.get()):
        ls1.insert(END,row)
```